# Computed observable doesn't change when property of observable array item changes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am making my first steps with knockout.js. I have created this code, but it doesn't satisfy me, because my `self.totals()` function doesn't sum every time I change something in price column(it works only when I change whole `<tr>` by adding new, or deleting old ones). Where I did a mistake?
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdcUA/1191/)

```
var books = [
{
    name : "Javascript",
    author : "David Flanagan",
    genre : "learning",
    price : "100"
},
{
    name : "PHP",
    author : "Luke Welling",
    genre : "learning",
    price : "120"
}
/* some more books */
];
var bookModel = function (books) {
var self = this;
var rowId;
self.books = ko.observableArray(books);

var calculate = self.totals = ko.computed(function () {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.books().length; i++) {
        total = total + +self.books()[i].price;
    }
    return total.toFixed(2);
});


self.addBook = function () {
    self.books.push({
        name: '',
        author: '',
        genre: '',
        price: ''
    });
    calculate();
};

self.removeBook = function (book) {
    self.books.remove(book);
    rowId = book.name;
    console.log(rowId);
    updateLocalStorage();
    calculate();
};


function updateLocalStorage() {
    var localBook = JSON.parse(localStorage['table']);
    for (var i = 0; i < localBook.length; i++) {
        if (localBook[i].name == rowId) {
            localBook.splice(i, 1);
            localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify(localBook));
            break;
        }
    }
}


self.save = function () {
    localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify(books));
        calculate();
    };
};


        if (localStorage['table'] == '[]') {
      localStorage.clear();
       } 

if (localStorage['table'] !== undefined) {
    var local = JSON.parse(localStorage['table']);
    var viewModel = new bookModel(local);

}
else {
    var viewModel = new bookModel(books);
    localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify(self.books));
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Add your code to the question.

Comment: My jsfiddle. Is it not enough?

Comment: Max, StackOverflow has provided something awesome called StackSnippets. There's a reason behind that. `:)` Kindly use it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks for your recommendation. I will try it in future

Comment: Sure buddy... All the best with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical misunderstanding: an observable array notifies changes on its items, not on the properties of its items.

For example an observable array notifies changes when the whole list of elements is changed by a new one, or an element is added or an element is deleted. In your case, if you add a new book, or remove it, or change the list of books, your computed observable will be updated.

If you need your computed observable to react to changes in the books prices, then you need to make the `price` property observable. I.e. your array of books should look like this:

```
var books = [
{
    name : "Javascript",
    author : "David Flanagan",
    genre : "learning",
    price : ko.observable(100)
},
{
    name : "PHP",
    author : "Luke Welling",
    genre : "learning",
    price : ko.observable(120)
},
```

If the price is not an observable, ko has no way to detect that the price has changed, and that's way it doesn't happen.

You can do something like this for each book:

```
book.price = ko.observable(book.price)
```

to convert the regular property into an observable property (it can be easyly done in a loop). Remember to create the property as observable also on the `addBook` function.

As `calculate` is a computed observable that accesses the observable array you don't need to call it explicitly in `addBook` and `removeBook`, because this computed observable is automatically subscribed to the observables that it accesses, which are both the observable array itself, and the price of each book.

You can see all of this in the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbustos/vdcUA/1193/).

I have not updated the fiddle, to show how it works, but if you try to serialize or store the books the prices won't be savde because they're no longer properties, but functions. So, you have to reverse the process, i.e. for each book:

```
book.price = ko.unwrap(book.price)
```

or

```
book.price = book.price()
```

*NOTE: you should organize your code so that it's clear when you're converting the properties into observables and viceversa. If you're interested not only in the `price`, but on all the properties, you can use [ko.mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for both converting properties into observables and viceversa, with `ko.fromJS` and `ko.toJS`.*

Comment: sorry, but one more question: why after you have updated jsFiddle I can't save current price value in localStorage?

Comment: Don't call it mistake. Call it lack of experience ;)

Answer (score 1):

As JotaBe mentioned, the individual elements that you're editing aren't observables. `self.books` is an observableArray, which only notices row-level changes.

An alternative to making elements into observables is, when a value changes, to notify the observableArray that it has been changed. Observables have a `valueHasMutated` property for that purpose. In your case, you're interested in changes to books, so you can bind to the change event there.

```
<td><input class='required form-control number' data-bind='value: price, event: {change: $parent.books.valueHasMutated}, uniqueName: true' /></td>
```

This is a somewhat hacky approach, as pushing changes up to higher-level structures can cause unnecessary dependency firing, but it can be a convenient work-around in some situations.

Comment: When I test your code it comes some mistake : Uncaught TypeError: this.notifySubscribers is not a function

Comment: {change: $parent.books.valueHasMutated () }

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle (ignore the change I made to genre): http://jsfiddle.net/vdcUA/1195/
You want a function, not an invocation of it.